# CSS max-size for and image in a fluid column, issue with IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, max-size

I have this code that works for all browsers except IE (of course :))
IE doen't reduce the size of the picture...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
.container {
    width:80%
}
.col1 {
    display: table-cell;
    background:#0F0;
    width: 200px;
}
.col2 {
    display: table-cell;
    background:#078;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">Patque, ut sit species matrimonii, dotis nomine futura coniunx hastam et tabernaculum </div>
  <div class="col2">>Post hoc impie perpetratum quod in aliis quoque iam timebatur, tamquam licentia crudelitati indulta per suspicionum nebulas aestimati quidam noxii damnabantur. quorum pars necati, alii puniti bonorum multatione actique laribus suis extorres nullo sibi relicto praeter querelas et lacrimas, stipe conlaticia victitabant, et civili iustoque imperio ad voluntatem converso cruentam, claudebantur opulentae domus et clarae. <img src="image.jpg" width="599" height="400" /></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has an idea, thanks in advance

Comment: You've defined the width for col1 but not col2. Just define the width then see it must be working...

Comment: I cannot put a width for the col2, it's the fluid column for the content...